# Unable to include gundb SEA for gun.user()?

Tags: gun

How to properly initiate the gundb.user() chain?

already tried this but cant make it worked.

```
let Gun = require('gun');
require('gun/sea');
```

and

```
let Gun = require('gun');
require(path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules/gun/sea.js'));
```

but I am still getting this on `npm start`

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think if you use 9.998, that will fix it.